# Boost strands post causing segmentation faults when accessing/inserting values

Tags: c++, c++11, post, boost, asio

I'm currently writing a networking structure that merely enacts a server to listen on it's own strand, simple. Whenever the strand is called to call a function and that function calls any members from within the class, segmentation faults occur.

There are a few exceptions but notably these segmentation faults occur when

1. tcp::acceptor myAcceptor(my_io_service, myEndpoint)
2. mySockets.insert(...)

Now I could easily swap myAcceptor and place it within the initializer list within the constructor and treat it as a class member but I would like to avoid that.

So whats next to validate my claim? My latest attempt was checking the size of the mySockets which, I should note, is a **map**. I checked the size **prior** to calling myStrand.post(...) and checked the size within the function call. Here is what I noticed.

The mySockets map sizes:

1. **Prior to post**: 0 (Nothings been inserted, great!)
2. **Within function call, called by post**: 999929272 (Ughhhh)

It appears something went airy but what exactly? Did it create a new instance but oddly wouldn't this be 0? It couldn't have lost the address as this would surely cause a segmentation fault, wouldn't it?

This is where I'm at right now in my debugging process.

**Goal**

The final goal is to be able to have access to mySockets and my_io_service within the post strand.

**Layout flow**

This explains the layout, the good ol code is below

1. Create 'work' by passing io_service
2. Start the io_service by invoking .run()
3. Create the TCP server
4. Assign parameters to the class member types
5. Invoke myStrand.post(...) to call the servers, listen for connecting clients
6. Wait for client to connect, etc

I've selected code samples that detail the problem.

**Header file**

```
using boost::asio::ip::tcp;
bool amIConnected = false;
boost::asio::io_service::strand myStrand;
boost::asio::io_service& my_io_service;
std::map<std::string, std::shared_ptr<tcp::socket>> mySockets;
tcp::acceptor myAcceptor
```

**Source file**

```
ConstructorStuff::ConstructorStuff(boost::asio::io_service& the_service) : 
myStrand(the_service), 
my_io_service(the_service),
myAcceptor(the_service, tcp::endpoint(tcp::v4(), 1337))
{}

void ConstructorStuff::CreateTheServer()
{
    amIConnected = true;
    // std::cout << mySockets.size() << std::endl; Returns 0
    mStrand.post(std::bind(&ConstructorStuff::ListenForConnection, this));
}

void ConstructorStuff::ListenForConection()
{
    // std::cout << mySockets.size() << std::endl; Crazy size
    tcp::acceptor tryAgain(my_io_service, tcp::endpoint(tcp::v4(), 1338)); // Just to showcase the error doesn't just occur through mySockets.
}
```

**Where ConstructorStuff is called**

```
void SetupServer()
{
    ConstructorStuff stuff(some_service);
    stuff.CreateTheServer();
}
```

**This calls the function above**

```
ServiceStarter spinup(service);
spinup.Start(); // Just queues reference_service.run()
std::shared_ptr<SomeClass> server_interface(new SomeClass ( service ));
server_interface->SetupServer();
boost::this_thread::sleep(boost::posix_time::seconds(20));
server_interface->Cancel(); // Just another function that kills the server.
```

Any suggestions would be great!

**Side notes**:

- Any additional values like say **myPort** placed in the header file, initialized to 1337 in **CreateTheServer()** and then called in **ListenForConnection()** will abruptly be different.
- To reassure anyone that may ask, these values may be accessed **OUTSIDE** the strand, thus locking down this problem to a strand related issue that I'm having.

**Edit**

I added two new source files. I'm quite limited to what I can show but this should be enough to illustrate the problem.

Comment: You should show more code, for example how `ConstructorStuff` is created, where is `io_service::run` called, and what is the lifetime of `ConstructorStuff`.

Comment: @rafix07 Added two new code samples, bottom one calls the one above it.

Comment: `stuff` is local variable inside `SetupServer`, after `CreateTheServer` is called, `stuff` is detroyed when function `SetupServer` ends , then *somewhere (by io_service)* `ListenForConection` is called for unexisted object (that is why you are getting strange results), so it is undefined behaviour. `stuff` must exist as long as you call its method. You can create `ConstructorStuff ` onto heap, or make `stuff` to be data member of some class to extend its lifetime. You need to be aware that `post` queues passed handler, and they are called by `io_service` in `run` method.

Comment: But when these handlers are called you don't know. But you need to ensure that handler created from member function will be called on existing object i.e. on `stuff`.

Comment: I'm actually working on this right now to see if it pulls through, I believe you might be right.

Comment: @rafix07 If you draft up an answer, I'll vote it as so. The problem was indeed losing sight of the object. I would've thought that it would throw a seg fault error to better illustrate that it lost scope =O

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem comes from `SetupServer` where `stuff` is local variable, so after `CreateTheServer` was called, `stuff` was destroyed and somewhere by `io_service::run` handler posted by `mStrand.post(std::bind(&ConstructorStuff::ListenForConnection, this));` was called on deleted object. Then `std::cout << mySockets.size() << std::endl;` printed strange result - it is a simple example of undefined behaviour.